# Hyperledger Fabric not working in accordance with its documentation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Using a MacBook Pro, Big Sur OS, I followed the hyperledger fabric [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v2.2.1/dev-setup/devenv.html), I installed all the required files and tools.  However, when I reached to the final step, the code generated a goimports error that I am not able to repair.
The Error was the following:

```
johnny@JohnnyMBP fabric % make basic-checks integration-test-prereqs
All files are excluded from having license headers
Building github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell -> misspell
Checking changed go files for spelling errors ...
spell checker passed
Checking for go:generate parent path references
Checking trailing spaces ...
DEP: Checking for dependency issues..
./scripts/check_deps.sh
Building golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports -> goimports
Building mvdan.cc/gofumpt -> gofumpt
Building honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck -> staticcheck
LINT: Running code checks..
./scripts/golinter.sh
Checking with goimports
The following files contain goimports errors
bccsp/factory/nopkcs11.go
bccsp/factory/nopkcs11_test.go
bccsp/factory/pkcs11.go
bccsp/factory/pkcs11_test.go
bccsp/factory/pkcs11factory.go
bccsp/factory/pkcs11factory_test.go
bccsp/pkcs11/pkcs11_test.go
core/handlers/library/noplugin_test.go
core/handlers/library/plugin.go
core/handlers/library/plugin_stub.go
core/handlers/library/race_test.go
integration/ledger/ledger_generate_test.go
internal/fileutil/syncdir.go
internal/peer/node/signals.go
internal/peer/node/signals_windows.go
orderer/common/server/signals.go
orderer/common/server/signals_windows.go
The goimports command 'goimports -l -w' must be run for these files
make: *** [linter] Error 1
johnny@JohnnyMBP fabric %
```

This was my go environment results:

```
johnny@JohnnyMBP fabric % go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/johnny/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/johnny/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/johnny/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/johnny/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/johnny/github.com/webzest/fabric/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/vs/8twtz6352nb26pnpyqfk11j80000gn/T/go-build698966046=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Please provide some guidance that I can follow to complete the development environment for hyperledger fabric.

UPDATED:

I ran goimports -l -w on all the .go files and reran a make basic-check.  Now, I am getting a vendor error:

```
johnny@JohnnyMBP fabric % make basic-checks
All files have SPDX-License-Identifier headers
Building github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell -> misspell
Checking changed go files for spelling errors ...
spell checker passed
Checking for go:generate parent path references
Checking trailing spaces ...
DEP: Checking for dependency issues..
./scripts/check_deps.sh
Building golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports -> goimports
Building mvdan.cc/gofumpt -> gofumpt
Building honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck -> staticcheck
LINT: Running code checks..
./scripts/golinter.sh
Checking with goimports
Checking with gofumpt
Checking for golang.org/x/net/context
Checking for github.com/gogo/protobuf
Checking with go vet
Checking with staticcheck
The following staticcheck issues were flagged
vendor/github.com/dustin/go-humanize/number.go:76:9: constant  overflow (compile)
vendor/github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/leafnodes/benchmarker.go:82:25: constant  overflow (compile)
make: *** [linter] Error 1
johnny@JohnnyMBP fabric %
```

Has anyone successfully setup the development environment with the latest version of GO and the latest build on GIT for Fabric?  I need help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

- Use Go 1.16 (which is the version currently used to build/run Fabric).
- Use Go installed to /usr/local/go with the official installer rather than installed with Homebrew.

If there really is something wrong with the imports in those files, which there shouldn't be unless they have been modified locally, use the `goimports -l -w` command for each of the files listed to correct them.

For reference, I am also using a Macbook Pro, running MacOS Monterey but previously with Big Sur, and `make basic-checks` runs cleanly for me with Go 1.16.9 on the latest **main** branch code.

Comment: thank you.  I was able to install GO 1.16.7.  Right after the installation, the test ran all the way through the PKCS11 portion where it failed.  I tried to configure the PKCS11 from their online instructions, but was not able to get it going.  I think the Docs for Hyperledger Fabric Development environment page is not up to date with the current code and needs to be updated to allow a newbie to follow along and setup the dev env without issues.  What would you recommend?

Comment: Honestly, even though I do have softhsm installed so in theory could run all the tests locally, I find it too slow and problematic to do that on my machine. If I'm making code changes, I locally run the basic checks and unit tests for specific packages relevant to my changes, then push changes up for the Azure Pipelines build pipeline to check everything else is good while I get on with something else. Of course, other people might have different or better advice!